# GlassFish gives an error when launching a JRuby application from the admin console

Tags: glassfish, jruby

In GlassFish, after I click on launch, I am getting error on the following URL:
http://localhost:4848/common/applications/webApplicationLinks.jsf?appID=sk&contextRoot=/sk

When I deployed my WAR file and clicked on the launch link, I am getting an error in the browser. It's showing [two links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANrGO.png),

[image]

and when I clicked a link, it's giving me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i140U.png).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the second screenshot:

> Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2

It looks like you have mismatched versions. The easiest thing to do would be to update JRuby to the latest version.

Comment: when updated ruby  version 2.2.2 and also  Jruby  version  9.0.5.0 then  also  its giving same error

Comment: The exact same error? If so, then there is still some resource at the wrong version. Can you double check that the error hasn't changed at all? Can you also check that you've rebuilt your WAR properly.

Answer (score 0):

seems you're trying to deploy a Warbled .war but the backtrace indicates `GEM_HOME` does not get isolated properly (all gems should be resolved from the .war file since they are expected to be packed up). gems are picked up from RVM, maybe `rvm use system` or unset any `GEM_HOME`, `GEM_PATH` variable as launching Glassfish.